# How to merge rows from table based on a common ID? SAS EG

Tags: merge, sas, rows

I know there are some similar questions out there, but being a total noob, I would like to find the specific code that would work for me.

In a SAS EG project, I have a query result named WORK.QUERY_FOR_TABLE1 with 4 columns as:
ID1 ID2 TEXT1 TEXT2

As I have multiple ID2 per ID1, which is unique, I would like to merge rows based on ID1 and columns containing text with a divider, such as:
Source:

```
ID1 ID2 TEXT1 TEXT2
1   1   ABC   DEF
1   2   GHI   JKL
2   1   ABC   DEF
```

Result:

```
ID1 TEXT
1   ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
2   ABC
```

Any idea for the code (including calling in the query result I already have in the project)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add some actual SAS code into your Enterprise Guide project to do that.

Create a new variable and use CATX() function to build the string.  Use BY group processing.

```
data want;
  do until (last.id1);
    set QUERY_FOR_TABLE1 ;
    by id1 ;
    length text $200;
    text=catx(',',text,text1,text2);
  end;
  keep id1 text;
run;
```

Comment: Just want to say, this is a really useful piece of code and works fine in SAS in cloud (SAS VIYA) where the input is not sorted by id1